# random image showing quiz

Tags: java, netbeans

I've been working on java with netbeans to make a program which shows question (png images) randomly for about 1 min on screen. When image flashes on display, the user gets time to select his answer (out of 4 options). My code is:

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame
 */
private String[] images = {"a0.jpg","a1.jpg","a2.jpg","a3.jpg","a4.jpg","a5.png","a6.png"};
private int rand;
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    Timer time = new Timer();
    TimerTask image = new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            Random gen = new Random();
            rand = gen.nextInt(6);
            String image = images[rand];
            jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src\\images\\" + image));
            jLabel1.repaint();
            System.out.println(rand);

        }
    };
    time.schedule(image,100,900);

}
```

Everything is done correctly, but following problems are there:

1. Repeated question,
2. How to assign answer to every question (so that i can use if condition)

Comment: Create a `Question` and an `Answer` class, and go from there

Comment: Your use of the Random class doesn't look right to me.  It needs to be a class member, not part of that method.  If you want to prevent someone from seeing the same quiz more than once you have to keep track of what they've seen.  You give no indication of how users will interact with images to provide answers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

Have a Map with the question as a key and the answer as the value. You could either do this with a simple `Map<String, String>` or perhaps construct your own Question and Answer objects depending on what you need.

To avoid getting the same question twice, simply remove it from the Map once you've displayed it to the user.

```
Map<String, String> questions = new HashMap<>();

// Constructor where we put all the questions into the Map
public Main() {
    questions.put("What's 1 + 1?", "2");
    questions.put("What's the meaning of life?", "42");
}

public void printQuestion() {
    Random random = new Random();
    Map.Entry<String, String> question = (Map.Entry<String, String>) questions.entrySet().toArray()[random.nextInt(questions.size())];
    System.out.println("Question: " + question.getKey());
    System.out.println("Answer: " + question.getValue());
    questions.remove(question.getKey());
}
```